# Nivo Slider Glitch *Any Ideas?

Tags: jquery, css, slider, nivo-slider

When clicking next/prev on [this slider](http://clickpex.co.uk), the image flickers prior to the animation/transition.

Comment: First thing I would do is remove the HREF attribute from the anchor tags.

Comment: thanks for the help, just removed the /href/ and nothing changed :( any other ideas?

Comment: No glitch at all in FF, can you specify your problem properly.

Comment: Yea i've narrowed the issue down to just chrome, however the scripts work independently on their own, however once live on the net, chrome decides to reload the image when clicking next / prev before transitioning to the next slide

Comment: I've found some useful tips with regards to google chomes cache here;  http://goo.gl/onKG0